# Discord Bot Command to use random mention when a mention is not used. Having Issues

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Somewhat new to python and getting nowhere with getting this to work.
I get the following error on line 23 when typing the command without a mention:

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'**

I don't why it's trying to use this response section as its for when there's a mention, useless I'm missing something.

```
import discord
from redbot.core import commands
import random

class boop(commands.Cog):
    """My custom cog"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def boop(self, ctx, user: discord.User=None):
        """Boop Someone"""
        # Your code will go here
        author_name = ctx.author.mention
        member = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
        
        randomuser = [f"{author_name} booped {member.mention}",
                     f"{author_name} booped {member.mention} on the nose",
                     f"{author_name} booped {member.mention}'s snoot",
                     f"{author_name} gave {member.mention} a boop"]
                     
        mentionuser = [f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}",
                     f"{author_name} booped {user.mention} on the nose",
                     f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}'s snoot",
                     f"{author_name} gave {user.mention} a boop"]
        if not user:        
          await ctx.send(random.choice(randomuser))
        else:
          await ctx.send(random.choice(mentionuser))
```

Comment: could `member = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)`  be returning a value of None? Maybe there are no members in the guild?

Comment: Why are you setting `user`'s default value to `None`? When you don't mention a user, `user` will be `None`, and then you're trying to retrieve the `mention` attribute of a `NoneType`.

Comment: @EwanBrown Assuming the bot account is a member of the guild, there will always be at least one `Member`. `random.choice` would raise an `IndexError` anyway if `members` were to be empty.

Comment: You should move the `mentionuser` into the else statement where you verified if it is not `None`, that is likely to cause the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the command without a mention, `user` becomes `None` because that is the default value for the parameter that you set in the function definition.

Then:

```
mentionuser = [f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}",
                     f"{author_name} booped {user.mention} on the nose",
                     f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}'s snoot",
                     f"{author_name} gave {user.mention} a boop"]
```

You're trying to retrieve the `mention` attribute of a `NoneType`. That's where the error results from. To avoid this, include the `mentionuser` definition in the else block:

```
...
else:
  mentionuser = [f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}",
                       f"{author_name} booped {user.mention} on the nose",
                       f"{author_name} booped {user.mention}'s snoot",
                       f"{author_name} gave {user.mention} a boop"]
  await ctx.send(random.choice(mentionuser))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command()
async def boop(ctx, target:discord.Member=None):
  author=ctx.author.mention
  if not target:
    members=ctx.guild.members
    target=random.choice(members)
  target=target.mention
  responses=[f'{author} has booped {target}!', f'{target}, {author} has booped you!']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(responses))
```

this worked for me but i don't use cogs and my client call is different. i think your problem was that you were using user objects instead of members.